# ADB shell command uninstall Android app from Windows 7

Tags: android, shell, uninstallation

I am doing testing of app on Android emulator. I am able to install my app via this:

```
adb install camera_test_debug.apk
```

After installing, the app name appear in the list is "camera_test". However, I can't do the uninstall with `adb uninstall camera_test`. It will return failure message.

Why can't I uninstall? What should be the name I put in to be able to uninstall?

Thank you.

Comment: Check your app apk name .. and try again

Comment: @MD Yeah, tried with that. Same thing..

Answer (score 3):

```
adb uninstall package.yourapk.name
```

not

```
adb uninstall filename.apk
```

Check the AndroidManifest.xml, get the package name of your camera_test_debug.apk, eg. com.example.cameratest.

Then use "adb uninstall com.example.cameratest" to remove that apk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to add the name into the manifest file `<manifest package="com.example.cameratest" `, but I still can't uninstall. What am I missing here?

Comment: I am not asking you to add this name to your Androidmanifest.xml, you need to use the name you set in the xml file. It is mandatory for each app. To be more clear, you need to know the package name of the app you have already installed.

Answer (score 0):

you should uninstall your app by your package name so check your package name in manifest , then be sure that your app is debuggable.